# Ceiling Fan is hot 6' down, but lights nor fan comes on

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I've hooked up my hunter ceiling fan with black/blue wire connected to the black(hot) wire and my white to white(neutral) and green to ground wire.
My sniffer says that I'm hot not only at the ceiling level but also 6 feet down near the motor. However, even though I'm "hot" my lights don't come on nor does my fan. So is the brand new fan at fault here or did I do something wrong?

Jon

Comment: By "*sniffer*" you mean a non-contact voltage detector? If so, that just shows that there's voltage "*down near*" the motor. It doesn't show that there's a complete circuit, or that there's power to the fan/lights. Use a multimeter or voltmeter, and test for voltage between the black/blue wires and the white wire. Check for voltage at the light sockets, and at the motor. Make sure the wall switch (if applicable) is installed properly, and not switching the neutral.  Are the pull switches in the proper state? Is the directional switch in the proper position?

Comment: well, that would make sense. So possibly the sniffer(voltage detector) would still work even if my neutral wires may not be connected?

Comment: Yes, the non-contact voltage tester will work even if the neutral is not connected.  [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_light#Non-contact_voltage_detectors) explains how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you turn the fan on!  No seriously, it probably has a pull cord in addition to the switch that may not be obvious (plus a direction switch that might be stuck in the middle or something) You could always install a dummy load like a light bulb to test it